# How do i get downline of userid in a table with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Currently i'm using php and mysql to fetch downlines of a particular userid. Is there any way i can just use mysql to do that. My code is......

```
function downlineSearch($mid, $s) 
{
    global $nums; global $str;
    $q = $cn->query("SELECT userid, CONCAT(lastname,' ',firstname,' ',middlename) AS name FROM clientsdata WHERE (recid LIKE '%$s%' OR lastname LIKE '%$s%' OR firstname LIKE '%$s%' OR middlename LIKE '%$s%') AND sponsor = $mid");
    while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
    {
        $nums += 1;
        $str .= "<tr><td valign='middle'>NRN".$r['userid']."CCN</td><td valign='middle'>".$r['name']."</td></tr>";
        downlineSearch($r['userid'], $s);
    }
}

$str = '';
downlineSearch($mid, 'janet');
echo '<table id="tblSearch" width="100%">';
echo "<tr><td colspan='4' align='center' style='padding-top:10px;'><h3> $nums records found for [ <span style='color:red'>".$_POST['s']."</span> ]</h3></td></tr>";
echo $str;
echo '</table>';`
```

PLEASE ANY HELP WOULD BE HIGHLY APPRECIATED. THANKS

Comment: what do you mean by `downlines of a particular userid`. Surely you will need a parameter to restrict the record in your query

Comment: Where does $cn variable come from?

Comment: $cn is a variable to mysqli connection to database. The downline is like a network map, like user a is connected to user a1, a2, a3 and a1 is connected to a11, a12. like generation to generation.... so i want to get how many generation a has. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

My guess it that you need to set the value of $cn, probably something like that:

```
    $cn = new mysqli;
```

Does that help?

What is the error message you are getting?

Do you know in which line the error happens?

Do you have ability to debug line-by-line and view variables? If not, add several "echo" statements, to view in browser what's going on. Or, use error_log(), to display info in PHP error log, if you have access to it.

(I'm sorry about asking for clarification in an "answer", but the system does not let me add comments to other people's question - yet. As soon as you add some clarification, I will revise this "answer" to be actual answer to your question.)

Comment: the php function is working perfectly just that i want to know if there is a better and more efficient way to do it with mysql only... like mysql procedure or.... Thanks!

Comment: You could move all the work into a stored procedure, but keep the same basic algorythm. The number of SELECTs would be the same, but you would only run $cn->query() once. If your connection between PHP and batabase is slow, that might speed it